# Counterexample to: "If a function is continuous in a point $x_0$ then it is defined in a neighborhood of that point."

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm looking for a counterexample to the statement:

> If a function is continuous in a point $x_0$ then it is defined in a
>   neighborhood of that point.

If I take

$f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x):=x$

Then it is continuous in any point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ since $lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=x_0 \forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, nevertheless it is not defined in any neighbourhood of any point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is this counterexample correct?

**Edit**

Definition of neighborhood of $x_0$: Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$ a real number. We call a neighborhood of $x_0$ with radius $r$ the open and bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ $(x_0-r,x_0+r)$.

Definition of limit: Let $x_0$ be a limit point for a function $f(x)$. We write $lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)=l \iff \forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta >0 \mid \forall x\in domf \wedge 0<\mid x-x_0 \mid <\delta \implies \mid f(x)-l\mid <\epsilon$

Definition of continuity of $f$ in $x_0$: $f$ is continuous in a point $x_0$ of its domain iff $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 \mid \forall x \in dom(f) \wedge \mid x-x_0 \mid < \delta \implies \mid f(x)-f(x_0)\mid <\epsilon$

Comment: What is your definition of neighborhood?

Comment: The word "neighborhood" is relative to a set. So it is unclear what you are really asking. For example, the neighborhoods of $0$ in $\mathbb Q$ are different from the neighborhoods of $0$ in $\mathbb R$. So it is definitely possible to define a function on $\mathbb Q$ that is continuous at $0$, but isn't defined on the irrationals. But it is still defined on a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Note that it is always possible to have "$x\to x_0$" without requiring there be an interval of values through which $x$ travels (I'm assuming you're thinking about the real line). You can approach a point through discrete points, or even through a finite number (including only the point itself) of points.

Comment: "Defininition of continuity that uses limits" is not actually a useful definition. What does the definition mean, when there are lots of points where the function isn't defined? What does $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$  mean then?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I added the "epsilon-delta" definition, but, as far as I know, that is equivalent to the condition $lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$ if $x_0$ is a limit point in the domain of $f$ (and that is the case). The definition of limit does not require that the function is defined in **every** point of a neighborhood of $x_0$

Comment: @Gianolepo It depends on your definitions of that **and** neighborhood. You seem to be using non-standard versions of both those words.

Comment: If this is related to an actual problem from homework or a book somewhere, could you give us the full statement of the question? Again, it reads like you might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's not from a problem, I reported all the definitions as on my textbook.

Comment: There's a much easier function definition with domain $\{0\}$ and $f(0)=0$. This is also continuous at $0$, and the domain nothing but $0$. The point is, the usage of "neighborhood" in this case is flawed - when we are talking about a function, the "neighborhood" of a point is a subset of the domain of the function, not of some wider space it may or may not belong in.

Comment: A more common function is $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ defined on the non-negative integers. Again, continuous at $0$, but not defined on any neighborhood of $0$ in the real line.

Comment: Thomas is right. The definition of a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ suggests the function is defined on $X$. So, the answer to your questions depends on the topology on $X$ (which also dictates the continuity of $f$)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the following definition your counterexample is correct. You could take $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ for an even simpler example with a dense domain.

Let $x \in X$. If $f:X \to Y$ then we say that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$d_Y(f(x),f(y)) < \varepsilon$$

whenever
$$y\in X, ~ d_X(x,y) < \delta$$

Note that this definition is equivalent to yours when $x$ is a limit point of the domain.

Comment: Well, your definition requires $f$ to be defined on all of $X$. That's not the case for our OP, who is not talking about neighborhoods in $X$ but in some space containing $X$.

Comment: That's precisely the point. The neighb. in this bigger space have nothing to do with the continuity of $f$. Also, $X$ is just the domain of $f$ so I don't understand what you mean by his definition not requiring $f$ to be defined in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $f^{-1}(\mathrm{open})$ is open. So $f$ has to be defined in a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Answer (score -2):

No, this is not a valid counterexample because $f$ is not continuous anywhere which I will show as follows.

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x) \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0: [x \in V_\delta(x_0) \implies f(x) \in V_\varepsilon(x_0)]$$

(where $V_a(b)$ is the open $a$-neighbourhood of $b$)

For any $\varepsilon,\delta>0$, I can obviously pick for $x$ any rational $q \in V_\delta(x_0)$, in which case $f(x)$ will not be defined and thus cannot be an element of $V_\varepsilon(x_0)$.

Comment: Since OP is talking about limit points I assume his definition of limit is not so naive.